# maintaining state for in-app purchases in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I got sample code online about in-app purchases. When the purchase completes, I want a value to state it is bought.

For example, an integer within the app could be equal to 1 or a string could say "Bought". The user will not see this, it is just for reference. When the user goes to the storefront next time, if they hit a button, I want it to check to see if this value is equal to 1 or Bought. If it is, I will have it move to the next page from there.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial on In-App Purfchases](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/).

### Edit:

There are quite a few ways to achieve what you are looking for. No one will write your code for you *( unless you hire them ;-D )*. You should look more into the StoreKit framework to get a better understanding of how it works. You will then learn how to manage purchases and how to check if an item is purchased.

For In-App purchases, I like to use [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/)'s [In-App Purchase](http://urbanairship.com/products/in-app-purchase/) classes.

This is how I keep local tabs on items purchased in one of my apps:

```
+ (void) updateProductsFromPurchases
{
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:PRODUCT_IDS] == NO) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Products" ofType:@"plist"] 
                                                toPath:Strings(DOC_DIR,@"/Products.plist")
                                                 error:nil];
    }
    /*  update our product id list so we display updated products to the user  */
    NSArray *downloads = [FILEMANAGER contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:DOWNLOADS error:nil];
    for (NSString *purchased in downloads) 
    {
        if ( [purchased hasPrefix:@"com"] ) 
        {
            /*  for each purchase, add it to the list of product id's  */
            NSMutableArray *addPurchase = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:PRODUCT_IDS];
            /*  this is to make sure we don't add duplicate product id's  */
            if ( ! [addPurchase containsObject:purchased] ) 
            {
                [addPurchase addObject:purchased];
                [addPurchase writeToFile:PRODUCT_IDS atomically:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That really didn't help. I'm still a little confused. Could someone please take a few minutes and write the lines of code? Thanks, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Everyone may handle their purchased items differently, maybe post some of the code you use to check your purchases. I have edited my answer with an example of how I check for my purchases and handle them accordingly.